# Is it possible to extract subrip subtitle from mkv video file with aws mediaconvert

Tags: amazon-web-services, caption, ffprobe, aws-media-convert

I want to know if it's possible to extract subRip captions from an MKV file with aws mediaconvert , i tried with "embedded" and "ancillary" but it does not seem to work [Image of was mediaconvert captions options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfCjy.png)

here is the ffprobe of the caption i want to extract from the file

```
{
  "index": 3,
  "codec_name": "subrip",
  "codec_long_name": "SubRip subtitle",
  "codec_type": "subtitle",
  "codec_time_base": "0/1",
  "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
  "codec_tag": "0x0000",
  "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
  "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
  "time_base": "1/1000",
  "start_pts": 0,
  "start_time": "0.000000",
  "duration_ts": 2860832,
  "duration": "2860.832000",
  "disposition": {
    "default": 0,
    "dub": 0,
    "original": 0,
    "comment": 0,
    "lyrics": 0,
    "karaoke": 0,
    "forced": 0,
    "hearing_impaired": 0,
    "visual_impaired": 0,
    "clean_effects": 0,
    "attached_pic": 0,
    "timed_thumbnails": 0
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "eng",
    "title": "English",
    "BPS-eng": "70",
    "DURATION-eng": "00:46:32.320000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng": "661",
    "NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng": "24777",
    "_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng": "mkvmerge v34.0.0 ('Sight and Seen') 64-bit",
    "_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng": "2019-11-17 11:19:25",
    "_STATISTICS_TAGS-eng": "BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES"
  }
},
```

Comment: You can extract them with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I know but i want to do it with aws mediaconvert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off the documentation, I would say this is not supported today in the service.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/captions-support-tables-by-container-type.html